# Hadoop Comparator method compare is not calling from the class of composite key

Tags: java, hadoop

I am learning Hadoop from *Hadoop: The Definitive Guide*. In this book there is one example of secondary sort: **MaxTemperatureUsingSecondarySort**

In this example I have added the class `IntPair` (which is same as in chapter 4's **Text Pair** class). I have written all the code in Eclipse, and when I wrote the below code:

```
IntPair.compare(ip1.getFirst(), ip2.getFirst());
return -IntPair.compare(ip1.getSecond(), ip2.getSecond());
```

then `IntPair.compare` is causing an error, saying that the compare method is not in `IntPair` class.

1. Do I need to also define the compare method in the `IntPair` class, and if it is so, then what will be the body type of the compare method?
2. Since the compare method is implemented by the `WritableComparator` interface, isn't there no need to define the body again in the `IntPair` class? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can anyone please give a comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have to define the compare method in `IntPair` class.

```
public int compare(IntPair tp) {
        int cmp = this.first.compareTo(tp.first);
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
        return this.second.compareTo(tp.second);
    }
```

The following is the compare method in secondary sort comparator:

```
public int compare(final WritableComparable firstValue,
            final WritableComparable secondValue) {
        final IntPair ip1 = (IntPair ) firstValue;
        final IntPair ip2 = (IntPair ) secondValue;

        final int cmp = ip1.getFirst().compareTo(ip2.getFirst());
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }

        return -ip1.getSecond().compareTo(ip2.getSecond()); // reverse
    }
```